# How can I avoid using a foor loop when there are additional parameters required?

Tags: r

I am learning R and have written some code which produces the desired outputs but uses loops, which I would like to reply with some type of `apply` function.

I have a data frame, `results`, which stores outcomes of matches of a two-player game.

```
Player1   Player2   Result
Alice     Bob       Win
Charlie   Dennis    Win
Elena     Frank     Loss
...
```

And another, `scores`, which stores each player's overall score.

```
Player    Score
Alice     1200
Charlie   1200
Frank     1200
Bob       800
Dennis    800
Elena     800
...
```

The way the scores are calculated is using a function which takes in a single result, the current scores, and returns a new data frame with the new scores.

```
updateScores <- function(result, scores) {
  [ Code that calculates new scores based on a single result ]
  return(scores)
}
```

Now the problem is that I want to loop through the results and update the scores table. This is trivial with a for loop:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(results)) {
  scores <- updateScores(results[i, ], scores)
}
```

But I am struggling to see how I can do this with `apply`, `mapply`, or any other functional way which avoids the loop. This is because the `scores` variable needs to be passed to `updateScores` and updated with every iteration. (In Lisp I would use the `reduce` function but in R, `Reduce()` doesn't work the same way.)

Comment: It would help to know what exactly you are trying to do and what you expect, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Basically you could do this with `sapply(1:nrow(results), function(x)updateScores(results[i, ])` assuming the updating is independent of previous scores and calculations. But there is likely a trivial solution using vectorized functions avoiding `apply` functions altogether. We are however unable to help with this, as we do not know the intricates of the `updateScores` function.

Comment: @Oliver The `updateScoes` function calculates the Elo rating of the two players involved in the single game passed as an argument. But in general, assuming the function in question isn't a simple one, would you use `sapply` here?

Comment: @Bulat What am I missing? The objective is to do exactly what I have done with the for loop, on the data given, but without using a for loop. I am coming from an OOP background and I'm doing this exercise to understand functional programming in R better.

Comment: In general you are not going to gain speed from using `*apply` functions over an optimized `for loop`, outside parallelization of your calculations. If your calculations are always using 2 players, there is however very much the chance, that you could split your data into `player 1 vs player 2` data styles, and perform the entire operation for these splits of your data, and gain quite a speed improvement. Basically convert your data into 'nice' formats first, and then perform calculations efficiently.

Comment: A preview of your data using `dput` might be helpful, in this situation. Is the reason for the question code that is running slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar idea to Oliver, as in no loops, but adapted to the existing data structure.

#### Example data

```
results <- read.table(text="
Player1   Player2   Result
Alice     Bob       Win
Charlie   Dennis    Win
Elena     Frank     Loss
June      Rashida   Tie", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

scores <- read.table(text="
Player    Score
Alice     1200
Charlie   1200
Frank     1200
Bob       800
Dennis    800
Elena     800
June      900
Rashida   1100", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

#### Functions

```
# expected score
exps <- function(ra, rb) {
    d <- (rb - ra)/400
    1/(1 + 10^d)
}

# update ratings
updrmulti <- function(ra, rb, score, k=16) {
    if (NCOL(ra) == 3) {
        rb <- ra[,2]
        score <- ra[,3]
        ra <- ra[,1]
    }
    ea <- exps(ra, rb)
    eb <- 1 - ea
    sa <- score
    sb <- 1 - sa
    cbind(ra=ra + k*(sa - ea), rb=rb + k*(sb - eb))
}
```

#### Implementation

```
# set Player names as rownames. Makes look-up easier
rownames(scores) <- scores$Player

# copy results data.frame
r2 <- results

# recode results to numeric
r2$Result <- (match(r2$Result, c("Loss", "Tie", "Win"))-1)/2

# replace Player names with their respective ratings
r2[,1:2] <- scores[as.matrix(r2[,1:2]), 2]

# pass new ratings+score data.frame to ratings-update function
r2u <- updrmulti(r2)

# cast updated ratings to new data.frame and give appropriate rownames
scores.new <- data.frame(Score=c(r2u))
rownames(scores.new) <- as.matrix(results[,1:2])

# order rows by rownames of original data.frame
scores.new[rownames(scores),, drop=FALSE]
#             Score
# Alice   1201.4545
# Charlie 1201.4545
# Frank   1201.4545
# Bob      798.5455
# Dennis   798.5455
# Elena    798.5455
# June     904.1560
# Rashida 1095.8440
```

Comment: Marking this as correct since it works for the given data and it takes into account draws. Thanks as well.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments we learned that the main problem of the question is calculating [Elo ratings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system). Without much more info, i would expect the problem is optimizing code for speed.

Rather than using an `apply` function over a `for loop` a great speed improvement can be achieved, by first converting ratings into `player 1 vs player 2` structures and converting code to use vectorized computations. Take the example implementation below:

```
Probability <- function(R1, R2)
    1 / (1 + 10^((R1 - R2)/400))
EloRating <- function(R1, R2, K, d){
    P1 <- Probability(R2, R1)
    P2 <- Probability(R1, R2)
    index <- d == 1 #Which matches did Player 1 win?
    #Use that d is 0 and 1's, and !d is 1 and 0's (reverse of d)
    R1 <- R1 + K * (d  - P1) 
    R2 <- R2 + K * (!d  - P1) 
    #output updated ratings
    return(list(Rating1 = R1, Rating2 = R2))
}
```

Note the lack of `for loop` and `apply` functions such as `sapply`.

This piece of code is highly optimized, as `Probability` can take any 2 vectors and return a vector of same length, using only the build-in functions of `R` which are themselves implemented in optimized `C` or `Fortran` code.

The `EloRating` function itself is also very optimized. First we calculate the probability (under normality assumption i'm guessing?) of either player winning. Next I'm assuming that an input vector `d` of victories are given, for which `d[i]==1` is indicative of player 1 winning the match against player 2, and any other result being the reverse.

I like having player 1 winning being marked as 1, and having player 2 winning marked as 0, so i use `d==1` to ensure that `d` only contains 1's (`TRUE`) and 0's `FALSE`.

When I've ensured this i can abuse that a logical vector can be inverted by using `!d`, reversing which elements are 1's and which are 0's. Thus i can perform all the rating changes simultaneously using only 2 lines of code.

For a bit of speed testing, let's run a microbenchmark for 1000 observed matches

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000
R1 <- rnorm(n, 1000, 50)
R2 <- rnorm(n, 1000, 50)
wins <- sample(1:2, n, replace = TRUE)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(EloRating(R1, R2, 40, wins), times = 1e3)
#output
Unit: microseconds
                        expr     min     lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
 EloRating(R1, R2, 40, wins) 289.983 291.87 305.2853 293.381 309.239 626.03  1000
```

Note the median time is `2.93 * 1e-6` seconds per iteration for 1000 players.

## Disclaimer

I have basically just converted code from [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/elo-rating-algorithm/) without any thought for it's correctness. I take no responsibility for any errors in the code, and i suggest checking against known results before using it.

Comment: Usually in a tie 0.5 points is given to each player, so `d` can't be expected to be binary.

Comment: That is good to know. I simply just read the wiki and converted an example code on geeksforgeeks, so it is by all means not meant as the perfect example. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, really appreciate you going into detail instead of just giving a quick solution.

Comment: Glad i could help with the understanding. Remember to throw an upvote for helpful answers and the answer marked, to help others find which answers provided guides, and to incentivize future answers. :-)